# Improve the execution time of Select query of SQL with JSON PATH , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL select query which returns 7K plus rows with 20 columns and converts that result set to JSON by using `FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES`.

It is taking around 7 to 9 seconds, but select query without `FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` is only taking 2 seconds. Is it possible to reduce from 7 to 9 sec to around 2 to 3 seconds?

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM TABLE A WITH(NOLOCK)
FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

Comment: Using the `NOLOCK` hint against a non-temporary table called `Temp` has so many code smells...

Comment: @Larnu corrected it and we can consider it as main table instead of temp table. Same performance issue after removing no lock from temp also.

Comment: Not sure how fast you expect 140,000 values to be munged into a string, or for the resulting string to be returned to SSMS and rendered, especially if some of those columns are large. Do you even know where the time is being spent? How fast is it if you say `SELECT A.* INTO #garbage FROM ...`?

Comment: The name was just one part, if I am honest. Why are you using `NOLOCK` at all?

Comment: The title *suggests* that `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` is the "problem", so are you saying that `SELECT A.* FROM TABLE A /*WITH(NOLOCK)*/ FOR JSON PATH` is "quick"?